# Let $R$ be a euclidean domain. For ideals $I, J\subseteq R$, prove that if $IJ = I ∩ J$, then $I + J = R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a euclidean domain. For ideals $I, J\subseteq R$, define $IJ$ to be the set 
$$
\{a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_n:n∈N; a_i∈I; b_j∈J\}.
$$

Prove that if $IJ = I ∩ J$, then $I + J = R$.

Attempt:

$d(I) \le d(IJ) = d(I ∩ J)$
$d(J) \le d(IJ) = d(I ∩ J)$

I tried to derive an equal relation between $I + J$ and $R$ but I got stuck here.

Comment: Any way you can add more work @Michael?

Comment: I+J={a+b:a∈A;b∈B} and IJ = {a1b1+⋯+anbn:n∈N;ai∈I;bj∈J}. how could I define I=(a),J=(b)?

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem**: If $R$ is a Euclidean Domain and $I, J$ ideals in $R$, then $IJ = I \cap J$ means that $I + J = (1)$.

**Proof**: Since $R$ is a Euclidean Domain and $I, J$ are ideals in $R$, then $I = (x)$ and $J = (y)$ for some $x, y \in R$ (since ED $\implies$ PID).

Note that
\begin{align*}
I + J &= \big( \gcd(x, y) \big)\\
IJ &= (xy) \\
I \cap J &= \big(\operatorname{lcm}(x, y) \big)
\end{align*}

Being a Euclidean Domain guarantees us existence of $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$, which we'll denote by $g$, $l$ respectively from now on.

Suppose $IJ = I \cap J$, then $(xy) = (l)$ and thus $l = xy \cdot w$ for some $w \in R$.

But by property of $l, g$, we have $lg = xy$ (this is one of the big properties of how the $\gcd$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ are connected) which means $lg = xy = xywg$.

Since $R$ is a Euclidean Domain, it's an Integral Domain, so we can cancel out and get $wg = 1$, hence $g$ is a unit. Thus $I + J = (g) = (1)$.

---

The converse also holds, but we can loosen the hypothesis a bit from Euclidean Domain to just Commutative Ring with identity:

**Theorem**: If $R$ is an Commutative Ring with identity and $I, J$ ideals in $R$, then $I + J = (1)$ means $IJ = I \cap J$.

**Proof**: Observe that $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$ always, so it suffices to show that $I \cap J \subseteq IJ$ with the given hypothesis.

Since $I + J = (1)$, there exist $i \in I, j \in J$ such that $i + j = 1$. Let $x \in I \cap J$, then $$x = x \cdot 1 = x \cdot (i + j) = ix + xj \in IJ = \bigg\{ \sum_i x_i, y_i : x_i \in I, y_i \in J\bigg\}$$
and we can conclude that $IJ = I \cap J$.